# Know the Job Name using SPID

Tags: sql-server

We had an issue, with Database restarted because transaction log space was full on the server. I have the spid which caused the issue but i cant figure out the job name under that spid.
Is there a way we can figure out the spid of all jobs over that ran last week ?

Comment: No, if you did not set up any audit, you cannot

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the answer but could point you in the right direction if your agent jobs are owned by different users. You can run the following to find the jobs that are owned by that particular SPID:

```
Use Master
Go

select 
    SJ.name,
    L.name
from  msdb.dbo.sysjobs SJ 
left join 
sys.syslogins L 
    on SJ.owner_sid = L.sid
Where 
    SJ.owner_sid = 'SPID_GOES_HERE'
```

However for a long term solution you might want to set you an audit that runs in the background to capture activity. [Here](https://www.sqlshack.com/various-techniques-to-audit-sql-server-databases/) is link that covers the different ways this can be done.

Hope this helps